# Laravel Redirect on trailing slash [ / ]

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel is redirecting from an **OPTIONS** method to a **GET** method.

web.php (Route)

```
Route::any('/files/{document?}','webDavController@dispatch')->name('webDav');
```

webDavController.php

```
private $allowMethods = array('options','get','head','post','delete','trace','propfind','proppatch','copy','mkcol','put');

public function dispatch(  $fileId = false  ){


        $method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

        if(in_array($method, $this->allowMethods)){         
            switch ($method){
                case "get":
                    $this->getFile();
                    break;
                case "put":
                    $this->putFile();
                    break;
                case "options":
                    $this->getOptions();
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Apache access logs

```
x.x.x.x - - [07/Jan/2020:10:49:37 -0500] "OPTIONS /files/ HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.21.0"
x.x.x.x - - [07/Jan/2020:10:49:37 -0500] "GET /files HTTP/1.1" 200 68280 "https://server.com/files/" "PostmanRuntime/7.21.0"
```

Why is this redirect happening ? How can I fix it, why is it rewrite to a **GET**? I did an apache mod-rewrite as suggested by other users but still with the issue, maybe I am not doing it correctly.